# juju hangs when connecting to mongo

Tags: juju, mongodb

Whenever I run any juju activity which connects to mongodb, the connection seems to connect OK but hang. I'm using the stable ppa and running on ubuntu 13.04 desktop.

```
$ juju status --debug
2013-09-05 18:03:09 INFO juju.environs.local environprovider.go:32 opening environment "local"
2013-09-05 18:03:09 DEBUG juju.environs.local environ.go:218 found "10.0.3.1" as address for "lxcbr0"
2013-09-05 18:03:09 DEBUG juju.environs.local environ.go:242 checking 10.0.3.1:8040 to see if machine agent running storage listener
2013-09-05 18:03:09 DEBUG juju.environs.local environ.go:245 nope, start some
2013-09-05 18:03:09 DEBUG juju state.go:138 waiting for DNS name(s) of state server instances [localhost]
2013-09-05 18:03:09 INFO juju open.go:69 state: opening state; mongo addresses: ["10.0.3.1:37017"]; entity ""
```

Below is the last few lines of `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`

```
Thu Sep  5 19:16:10 [conn2] end connection 10.0.3.1:35529 (0 connections now open)
Thu Sep  5 19:16:17 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.0.3.1:35873 #3 (1 connection now open)
```

Juju just stays in this state refusing to do anything.

Version information:

```
$ juju version
1.12.0-raring-amd64
$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.4
```

Edit: Mongo has auth disabled and is only running as a single node, SSL is off.

I'm not deploying mongodb, I'm using a lxc to test charms I'm building. mongodb is used by juju-local to hold lxc container state.

Here is my `mongodb.conf`: (comments removed)

```
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
logappend=true
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
port = 37017
journal=true
```

Comment: are you using mongodb authentication mode?

Comment: use mongodb shell and try to connect manually without any password ex: mongo 10.0.3.1:35873 Run show dbs if you get "need to login" message, then auth is on

Comment: nope if it is turned on it could be. is this a replica set?

Comment: did you "juju expose mongodb"

Comment: by default mongodb port is 27017 here it is connecting to 37017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with some help from the #juju IRC channel - I shouldn't be using the system mongo instance; juju creates its own when running `juju bootstrap`